# Windows application with ActiveX Control

Tags: wine, activex

A Windows Winforms application which makes use of msflexgrid built using visual studio runs correctly on windows.When the same application is made to run on ubuntu using wine ,there are series of errors and the exe does not work as expected.Dotnet framework has been installed using winetricks and also the msflxgrd.ocx is registered using the wine regsvr32 "path of the ocx file" command. Other exe files which do not make use of msflexgrid run as expected.
Can someone guide to effectively run .exe files containig msflexgrid.

The simple Vb code :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports AxMSFlexGridLib

Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private versionLabel As New Label()

    Private textBox1 As New TextBox()


    Public Sub New()

        Me.Text = "FlexGrid Example"
        Me.Size = New Size(500, 400)
        AxMSFlexGrid1 = New AxMSFlexGrid()
        AxMSFlexGrid1.Size = New Size(300, 200)
        AxMSFlexGrid1.Location = New Point(50, 150)
        Me.Controls.Add(AxMSFlexGrid1)

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        AxMSFlexGrid1.Rows = 3
        AxMSFlexGrid1.Cols = 3

        ' Populate the MSFlexGrid with data
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(0, 0, "Name")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(0, 1, "usn")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(0, 2, "college")

        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(1, 0, "John")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(1, 1, "123")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(1, 2, "XYZ")

        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(2, 0, "Adam")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(2, 1, "456")
        AxMSFlexGrid1.set_TextMatrix(2, 2, "PQR")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AxMSFlexGrid1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AxMSFlexGrid1.Enter

    End Sub

End Class
```

The errors I get when executing the file:

```
0024:fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" not implemented
0024:fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" not implemented
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0024:fixme:file:parse_samba_dos_attrib_data Unhandled user.DOSATTRIB extended attribute value.
Generated GUIDs only implemented for interfaces!
Could not load signature of MSFlexGridLib.IMSFlexGrid:get_Font due to: Could not
 load file or assembly 'stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo
ken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
 
 
 ===========================================================
        Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
 
=================================================================
        Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
          at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
          at System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_upgrade_remote_class_wrapper <0x
00012>
          at System.Object:__proxy_isinst_wrapper_MSFlexGridLib.IMSFlexGrid <0x0
0093>
          at AxMSFlexGridLib.AxMSFlexGrid:AttachInterfaces <0x0006f>
          at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost:GetOcxCreate <0x0004e>
          at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost:TransitionUpTo <0x00137>
          at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost:CreateHandle <0x00047>
          at System.Windows.Forms.Control:CreateControl <0x000b7>
          at System.Windows.Forms.Control:CreateControl <0x00073>
          at System.Windows.Forms.Control:CreateControl <0x001d3>
          at System.Windows.Forms.Control:CreateControl <0x00073>
          at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost:EndInit <0x0005b>
          at WindowsApp37.Form1:InitializeComponent <0x002ca>
          at WindowsApp37.Form1:.ctor <0x0009b>
          at System.Object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ <0x0006a>
          at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
          at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo:InternalInvoke <0x00012>
          at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo:InternalInvoke <0x0004b>
          at System.RuntimeType:CreateInstanceMono <0x00143>
          at System.RuntimeType:CreateInstanceSlow <0x0004f>
          at System.RuntimeType:CreateInstanceDefaultCtor <0x0005b>
          at System.Activator:CreateInstance <0x0009b>
          at MyForms:Create__Instance__ <0x00177>
          at MyForms:get_Form1 <0x0002b>
          at WindowsApp37.My.MyApplication:OnCreateMainForm <0x0002b>
          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBa
se:OnRun <0x00045>
          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBa
se:DoApplicationModel <0x000da>
          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBa
se:Run <0x000b3>
          at WindowsApp37.My.MyApplication:Main <0x00083>
          at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x0006c>
 
 
 
 
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000008 in 32-bit code (0x1000ea11).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:1000ea11 ESP:0050ede4 EBP:0050eea4 EFLAGS:00010206(  R- --  I   - -P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:04ae2e84 ECX:0050ed94 EDX:00000000
 ESI:04a88748 EDI:0050eea4
Stack dump:
0x0050ede4:  049e4350 04ae2f44 101c2b50 01019470
0x0050edf4:  04a88748 00000002 0050eea4 04ae2e58
0x0050ee04:  04a838e8 04a838e8 010851f8 01019470
0x0050ee14:  04ae31c8 04ae2e08 00000007 04ae2e0c
0x0050ee24:  000002c4 04ae9340 04a87e64 01019470
0x0050ee34:  01019470 00000002 04ae2de8 0050eea4
Backtrace:
=>0 0x1000ea11 in libmono-2.0-x86 (+0xea11) (0x0050eea4)
0x1000ea11 libmono-2.0-x86+0xea11: cmpw $0,0x8(%eax)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (89 modules)
PE  00370000-0038b000   Deferred        version
PE  00390000-003d6000   Deferred        shcore
PE  00400000-0040a000   Deferred        windowsapp37
PE  00810000-00a23000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  015d0000-01654000   Deferred        winex11
PE  01dc0000-01f84000   Deferred        wininet
PE  01f90000-01ff2000   Deferred        msacm32
PE  035c0000-03a3c000   Deferred        mscorlib
PE  03df0000-03e40000   Deferred        microsoft.visualbasic
PE  03e40000-045da000   Deferred        system.windows.forms
PE  045e0000-048a4000   Deferred        system
PE  048b0000-04930000   Deferred        system.drawing
PE  04930000-04956000   Deferred        system.configuration
PE  049a0000-049a8000   Deferred        accessibility
PE  08bd0000-08ce0000   Deferred        system.core
PE  08ce0000-08cf0000   Deferred        axinterop.msflexgridlib
PE  08cf0000-08d04000   Deferred        interop.msflexgridlib
PE  10000000-103ee000   Export          libmono-2.0-x86
PE  20da0000-20ddd000   Deferred        msflxgrd
PE  62240000-6231e000   Deferred        mscoree
PE  62500000-6290a000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  631c0000-63207000   Deferred        fusion
PE  643c0000-64449000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  64a80000-64ad8000   Deferred        win32u
PE  65680000-658fc000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  66080000-66179000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  66380000-667f8000   Deferred        ole32
PE  67500000-67553000   Deferred        imm32
PE  67bc0000-68043000   Deferred        comctl32
PE  684c0000-6860d000   Deferred        combase
PE  68880000-68d6a000   Deferred        user32
PE  69000000-69266000   Deferred        gdiplus
PE  69840000-6993b000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  6aac0000-6ad9c000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  6bbc0000-6bc57000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6c1c0000-6cb92000   Deferred        msxml3
PE  6da80000-6dc9f000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  6e200000-6e246000   Deferred        bcrypt
PE  6f240000-6f3bc000   Deferred        winmm
PE  70000000-70254000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE  70380000-70609000   Deferred        urlmon
PE  70d80000-70e20000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  712c0000-71314000   Deferred        mpr
PE  71400000-720af000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7b000000-7b52c000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b759000   Deferred        kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bebc000   Deferred        ntdll
ELF 7d000000-7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e537000-7e567000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e567000-7e5b7000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e5b7000-7e5da000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF 7e5da000-7e5e8000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF 7e5e8000-7e6b5000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e6b5000-7e7bd000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7e7bd000-7e930000   Deferred        win32u.so
ELF 7ee07000-7ee25000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ee25000-7ee65000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7ee77000-7f000000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f721f000-f72ae000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF f72ae000-f72f8000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.6
ELF f72f8000-f74a3000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF f74a3000-f7600000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF f7600000-f782e000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF f7832000-f783e000   Deferred        libffi.so.8
ELF f783e000-f7888000   Deferred        libnettle.so.8
ELF f7888000-f789f000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF f789f000-f78c2000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF f791a000-f7922000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF f7922000-f792f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF f792f000-f7944000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF f7944000-f7949000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF f7949000-f7958000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF f7958000-f7966000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF f7966000-f796e000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF f796e000-f7973000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f7973000-f7981000   Deferred        libmd.so.0
ELF f7981000-f7999000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF f7999000-f79a1000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF f79a1000-f79a7000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f79a7000-f79d5000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF f79d5000-f7b27000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF f7b27000-f7b3e000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF f7b3e000-f7b4a000   Deferred        bcrypt.so
ELF f7b4a000-f7b50000   Deferred        ws2_32.so
ELF f7b50000-f7c00000   Deferred        ntdll.so
ELF f7c00000-f7e35000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7e36000-f7e40000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF f7e44000-f7ed0000   Deferred        winex11.so
ELF f7ed8000-f7f10000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000020 (D) Z:\home\abc\abcd\Debug\WindowsApp37.exe
    00000024    0 <== 
    0000010c    0     SGen worker
    00000110    0     Finalizer
    0000011c    0     
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000004c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000070    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000090    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000b8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000e4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0     
    00000054    0     
    00000058    0     wine_sechost_service
    0000005c    0     
    00000060    0     
    00000064    0     
    000000c4    0     
00000068 winedevice.exe
    0000006c    0     
    00000074    0     
    00000078    0     wine_sechost_service
    0000007c    0     
    00000080    0     
    00000084    0     
    00000098    0     
    000000ac    0     
00000088 plugplay.exe
    0000008c    0     
    00000094    0     
    0000009c    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000a0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
000000a4 svchost.exe
    000000a8    0     
    000000bc    0     
    000000c0    0     wine_sechost_service
000000c8 explorer.exe
    000000cc    0     
    000000d0    0     
    000000d4    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000dc rpcss.exe
    000000e0    0     
    000000ec    0     
    000000f0    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000f4    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f8    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000fc    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000104 conhost.exe
    00000108    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-8.0.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 6.2.0-26-generic
```

Comment: this might just be a bug in the application that just gets hidden by something on windows happening in an ungaranteed, but specific order.

Comment: @Marcus Müller it is a simple code that works as expected on windows, attaching the code for your reference.

Comment: Seems the stdole.dll is missing.  Hint: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=30629